# Integer equation logarithmic

Tags: number-theory

I want to solve the equation $2^n=2k$ for $n$ even with $n,k \in \Bbb{N}$. I'm not sure how to go about this, using logarithm makes me enter the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The** solution is $m=1+\log_2k$. If $m$ is an integer, you are done; otherwise use
$\lceil m \rceil$ or $\lfloor m \rfloor$ depending on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$2^n=2k$ implies $2^{n-1}=k,$ so the solution set (n,k) is (2 r,2^{2 r-1}) for $r \geqslant 1.$